# How to duplicate a value of array and push it same array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am try to learn more about the JavaScript and I have one of the assignment where I have array and I need to duplicate that and return the result as below :

```
var smValue = [1,2,3];
```

`smValue.duplicate()` will give the output like :

```
[1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

I got stuck on that. I have tried to create function like that :

```
var smValue = [1,2,3]; 
fuction duplicate (){
    for(i=0;i<=smValue.length;i++){
        array[smValue.length + 1] = smValue.push(smValue[i]);  
    }
return array;
}

smValue.duplicate();
```

But failed. Please help me to resolve it. It may the vary basic but I have never seen this before.

Comment: Theoretical:
You loop thru the array and push each key back into the array

Practical:
for(var i = 0, len = smValue.length;i < len;i++) { smValue.push(smValue[i]); }

Comment: Yes same I thought but how can I assign the key to new item of the array?

Comment: You are pushing all values over `array[4]` key. In addition array wasn't declarated.

Comment: fails because your function isn't part of `Array.prototype` so you can't chain it to array itself

Answer (score 4):

A simple way would be to concat the array with itself:

```
function duplicate (arr){
    return arr.concat(arr)
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/msthu0f8/)

Or if you want to call it on the array itself.

```
Array.prototype.duplicate = function(){
    return this.concat(this)
}

smValue.duplicate() // returns [1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

Comment: This is the only answer that actually implements duplicate on the prototype, _and_ doesn't use a loop... +1

Comment: If i can do that normally with concat function then why we would use Array.protoType , Is there any specific reason?

Comment: Because if you want to do `var newarr = arr.duplicate();` you need to attach the method to the array prototype like Chris and I have shown in our answers. Otherwise you'll need to do `var newarr = duplicate(arr);`. Depends on the functionality you want, but in your question you wanted the first options.

Comment: okay that's fine, But can we do that without using concat function?

Comment: @Toretto, why dont you want to use concat? (if you dont then there are plenty of looping answers here already)

Answer (score 2):

The alternative (easier?) way is to use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
function duplicate(arr) {
  return arr.concat(arr);
}
```

To add this as a method on the array prototype:

```
if (!('duplicate' in Array.prototype)) {
  Array.prototype.duplicate = function () {
    return this.concat(this);
  };
}

[4, 5, 6].duplicate(); // [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/chf417un/3/)

Comment: He wants (/is required) to be able to call `duplicate` on the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
var duplicate = smValue.concat(smValue);
```

Concat 'merges' array's together, or a better word is joining them together.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution:

```
var smValue = [1,2,3];
smValue = smValue.concat(smValue);
```

Answer (score -2):

Theoretical:
You loop over the array and push each key back into the array using [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Practical:

```
var smValue = [1,2,3];
for(var i = 0, len = smValue.length;i < len;i++) { 
  smValue.push(smValue[i]); 
}
```

If you want to define new function that does it on every array, you want to do this:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3];


Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'duplicate', {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function duplicate() {
        for(var i = 0, len = this.length;i < len;i++) {
            this.push(this[i]);    
        }

        return this;
    }
});

console.log(myArray.duplicate());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4a8pw4u5/

I'm using Object.defineProperty to create non-enumerable property as Array.prototype.newDuplicate would add enumerable property.

And yes, you can use concat, but considering you tried to do it with a loop, I used for loop to show how to do it with that.